# Vlookup an array of formulas in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup

I have one table with two columns

```
ID     Probability
A      1%
B      2%
C      3%
D      4%
```

I have another table, with some IDs and corresponding weights:

```
ID   Weight
A    50%
D    25%
A    15%
B    5%
B    5%
```

What I'm looking for is a way, in a single formula, to find the corresponding probabilities for each of the IDs in the second table using the data from the first, multiply each by their respective weights from the second table, then sum the results.

I recognise a simple way to solve it would be to add a proxy column to the second table and list corresponding probabilities using a vlookup and multiplying by the weight, then summing the results, but I feel like there must be a more elegant solution.

I've tried entering the second table IDs as an array in both Vlookup and Index/Match formulas, but while both accept a range as a lookup value, both only execute for the first value of the range instead of cycling through the whole array.

I guess ideally the formula would

1. set an 1 x 5 array for the IDs,
2. populate a new 1 x 5 array based on the probabilities from the first table
3. multiply the new array by the existing 1x5 array for weights
4. Sum whatever is the result

[edit] So for the above example, the final result would be (50% x 1%)+(25% x 4%) + (15% x 1%) + (5% x 2%) + (5% x 2%) = 1.85%

The real tables are much, much bigger than the examples I've given so a simple Sum() function for individual vlookups is out.

Love to hear of any clever solutions?

Comment: I think you should show us the desired output.  "A picture is worth a thousand words" is a very true adage on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sure. For the above example, the output would be: 
(50% x 1%)+(25% x 4%) + (15% * 1%) +  (5% x 2%) + (5% x 2%) = 1.85%

Does that help?

Comment: No.  Update your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same ranges as given by Trương Ngọc Đăng Khoa:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A1:A4,D1:D5,B1:B4),E1:E5)`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula :

```
 {=SUM(LOOKUP(D1:D5;A1:A4;B1:B4)*E1:E5)}
```

With table in this :

```
    A   B    C  D   E   
1   A   1%      A   50% 
2   B   2%      D   25% 
3   C   3%      A   15% 
4   D   4%      B   5%  
5               B   5%
```

Comment: This will only work if the entries in A1:A4 remain in strictly ascending alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Great response, thanks guys!

XOR LX, your answer seemed to work in all cases, which is what I was looking for (and seems like it was much simpler than I'd originally thought). I think I misunderstood the way the SUMIF function works.

In case anyone is interested, I also found my own (stupidly complex) solution:

`=SUM(IF(A1:A4=TRANSPOSE(D1:D5),1,0)*TRANSPOSE(E1:E5)*B1:B4)`

Which basically works by transforming the thing into a 4 x 5 matrix instead. I think I still prefer the XOR LX solution for it's simplicity.

Appreciate the help, everyone!